# radiogroup tag not working: HTML5

Tags: html, radio-button, radio-group

**Summary:** I have a template which should contain radiogroup having 4 radio buttons. These values are used to change the layout of the specific block using css. 
example:

```
<radiogroup class="page-layout">
        <radio value="portrait-6-5">Portrait, width: 6.5 inches.</radio>
        <radio value="portrait-7-5">Portrait, width: 7.5 inches.</radio>
        <radio value="portrait-9">Portrait, width: 9 inches.</radio>
        <radio value="landscape-10">Landscape, width: 10 inches.</radio>
</radiogroup>
<div class="container report-block portrait-6-5">
     //block
</div>
```

the layout of ".report-block" will change when there is a change in radio buttons
reference: [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radiogroup)

**Issue:** I am using mozilla browser. Does it support radiogroup tag. I do not want to use `<input type="radio">`. Is there any other option.

Comment: Hm, your reference is related to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL to XUL, not HTML?

Comment: yes my bad. it is also a markup language. okay nevermind. Can you give me some suggestions to make it work

Comment: Use regular input buttons, why you wouldn't do it? Also, maybe some jquery workarounds are possible, but... don't see reason? :)

Comment: For the given example, it should be simple enough to use `<input type="radio">`, possibly with pure CSS.  I am using CSS with input radio buttons as tabs, and a container to show panel content (a "change" of layout that reveals one panel div corresponding to radio input "tab" selected).  This given example, however, doesn't demonstrate other instances where a complex grouping of various input types should be enabled or disabled depending upon which "top level" radio button is pushed.  Without knowing more about what was intended to achieve, it is impossible to demonstrate specifics.